# Forming adverbs from adjectives

Tags: adverbes

I am studying basics of adverbs and came across the following:

> Adjectif au féminin + «-ment » E.g. Certainement, lentement, doucement.

What does the author mean? What is “féminin” here: the subject, the object or the verb?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This rule is about forming an adverb from an adjective, not about using an adjective in a sentence.

What this rule says is that to form an adverb from an adjective, you take the (singular) feminine form of the adjective, and add the suffix “-ment”. Examples:

> certain → certaine → certainement
>   lent → lente → lentement
>   doux → douce → doucement
>   long → longue → longuement
>   actuel → actuelle → actuellement
>   actif → active → activement
>   financier → financière → financièrement
>   affreux → affreuse → affreusement

This rule is productive: you can take an existing adjective that has no corresponding adverb, and apply this rule to make a new adverb.

Beware that as with all etymological rules, there are exceptions.

Sometimes the *-e-* is pronounced with a semi-open sound `[e]` and takes an acute accent accordingly.

> confus → confusément
>   immense → immensément

Adverbs formed from a past participle don't take an extra *-e-*:

> modérer → modéré → modérément
>   étourdir → étourdi → étourdiment
>   devoir → dû → dûment

More generally, adverbs from an adjective that ends in a vowel usually don't take an extra *-e-* (but keep the existing *-e* if the adjective already ends with *-e*).

> aisé → aisément
>   joli → joliment
>   vrai → vraiment
>   absolu → absolument

Exception to the exception: *gai* → *gaiement*.

Adjectives that end in *-ent* or *-ant* lead to an adverb ending in *-emment* or *-ammant* (pronounced `[amɑ̃]` even when it's spelled *-emment*). There are a few exceptions (*lentement*, *présentement*) but the productive form is *-emment* or *-ammant*.

> courant → couramment
>   différent → différemment
>   savant → savamment

And some other exceptions that evolved on their own:

> gentil → gentiment

Comment: I would add that *nothing* in the adverb is feminine. Adverbs are genderless. The author conveyed not particular meaning: adverbs are just constructed that way.

Comment: "gentiment" is an interesting example. It seems like it could have been formed using the rule, making "gentillement," but then the more-or-less silent "lle" got dropped eventually.