# Can adjectives be used as adverbs?

Tags: grammaire, adjectifs, adverbes

I sometimes see things such as *Il parle vite*, when I would have thought it ought to be *Il parle vitement*. Are these interchangeable, or is the former technically wrong but casually permissible, or…?

What about in general?

*Il parle lente* vs *Il parle lentement*?

Or others…

Comment: In that sentence, *vite* is an adverb, not an adjective. The word *vitement* doesn't exist (anymore) in French. As for the use of *vite* as an adjective, it's really not common anymore, and has mostly been replaced by *rapide*.

Comment: Oooh, golden tips right there. Pro stuff. By the way, why do you live in Spain but mostly answer questions on FLU?

Comment: As for the general rule, I would say it's just a matter of "what sounds best". You would say *Il parle rapidement* but not *Il parle rapide*, and *Il parle fort* but not *Il parle fortement*. I fear it's just a matter of usage :(

Comment: @AlexisPigeon Dans « il parle fort », *fort* est un adverbe (qui se trouve être identique à l'adjectif dont il est dérivé, comme *vite*).

Comment: @Aerovistae Why the question, is such a thing prohibited? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. When grammar calls for an adverb, you need to use an adverb. You can't use an adjective, even in colloquial French.

> Il parle lentement.
>   * <s>Il parle lent.</s>

[Vite](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/vite) looks different because it's one of the few adverbs in French that don't have the suffix *-ment*. It is in the company of many common adverbs: *bien*, *mal*, *beaucoup*, *peu*, *très*, *toujours*, *jamais*, ...
Adding this suffix ([with the proper inflection](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/7268/forming-adverbs-from-adjectives/7272#7272)) to an adjective is the only productive rule to make new adverbs.

Note that *vite* is not an adjective in modern French (except in Québec).

A way to choose between adjectives and adverbs is to remember that an adjective qualifies a noun and agrees with it, whereas an adverb qualifies anything but a noun (verb, adjective, adverb) and is invariant (except for *tous*).

There is one exception which is sometimes classified as [“variable adverbs”](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morphologie_de_l%27adverbe_en_fran%C3%A7ais#Cas_particulier_des_adverbes_variables), although it could equally be classified as “adjectives qualifying adjectives”.

> des fleurs fraîches cueillies = des fleurs fraîchement cueillies
>   des portes grandes ouvertes

Apart from a few frozen idioms like “*porte grande ouverte*”, this is not in common use and the real adverbial form is preferred (at least in France): “*fleurs fraîchement cueillies*”.

Comment: The breadth and depth of your knowledge on the subject of French never cease to astound me.

Comment: I am french and I am learning things with this answer.

Comment: I like "Il parle lent". I'm going to start speaking like that. Will definitely give me a certain style ;-)

Comment: (don't do like me, it is NOT correct!)

Answer (score 0):

Le français classique n'a fait que progressivement la distinction entre adjectif et adverbe ; par exemple "coûter bon" signifiait "beaucoup" - on dit encore familièrement "coûter gros". Il ne faut donc pas s'étonner de voir chez les grands auteurs ce qui serait proscrit aujourd'hui (sans raison véritable : l'anglais est très libéral à ce sujet, sans que cela lui nuise).

Comment: Est-ce qu'on peut avoir des références et des dates ? *Coûter bon* et *coûter gros* n'étaient-ils pas des cas particuliers comme, par exemple, des contractions d'expressions originellement plus longues ?